# Cannot correctly input AVERAGEIF using age and gender

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using Excel 2016 and I have 3 Columns in a spreadsheet:

Column A = Date of birth

Column B= Gender (values are either M or F)

Column C= Age (Age is determined by `=DATEDIF(A1,TODAY(),"Y"`)

I am trying to get an average age by gender. I have tried `=AVERAGE(IF(B:B="F",C:C))` which produces a value of 0 and `=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"=F",C:C)` which produces `$NAME?`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Solved it. Thank you BigBen, correct input was `AVERAGEIF(B:B,"F",C:C)`

Comment: You may want to look into [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) (notice the `S` at the end)

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I am using Excel 2016

Comment: See the [`AVERAGEIF`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/averageif-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642) documentation. Try `=AVERAGEIF(B:B,"F",C:C)`.

Comment: Awesome, that was it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ideas for you, try

```
C1: ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(A1,TODAY(),0),0)
```

and then for your average column

```
D2: =AVERAGEIF(B:B,"M",C:C)
E2: =AVERAGEIF(B:B,"F",C:C)
```